# How to detect if the mouse is directly over an object type in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I need to detect (true or false) if my mouse is over a specific type of object.  There is one data template that the many objects use.  I do not need anything from an instance of an object, I just need to detect if my mouse is above this type of element on the UI.

It would be something along the lines of:

```
If(mouse.DirectlyOver == StorageElementWrapper)
{
...
}
```

EDIT: my error is that I am using my type like a variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to note that [`DirectlyOver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.directlyover.aspx) will very likely find something inside your element rather than the element you're actually looking for. To use this property, you'd want to look at the parent tree of the `DirectlyOver` element. Something along these lines, with `FindAncestorOrSelf` coming from [this blog post](http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/02/finding_ancestor_elements_in_w.html):

```
if (Util.FindAncestorOrSelf<StorageElementWrapper>((DependencyObject)mouse.DirectlyOver) != null)
{
...
}
```

Or if you have code references to your `StorageElementWrapper`s, (in this example, in a collection named `myWrappers`) and they derive from `UIElement`, this would probably be a better approach, using the [`IsMouseOver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ismouseover.aspx) property:

```
if (myWrappers.Any(x => x.IsMouseOver))
    // do something
```

Comment: I found out that you could just simply set `IsHitTestVisible` to `false` on those `UIElement`s that you "don't" wish to find. Thus ensure that the result is always what you're "actually looking for".

Answer (score 2):

A concept if you are interested in a particular item: create an `OnMouseOver` handler for that particular object (alternatively `OnMouseEnter`). Generally in WPF things work this event handling way rather than imperatively enumerating and discovering where is the mouse pointer. So this way the item itself can tell you if the mouse is over it. The item can have a public `readonly` property which exposes that, and your code can just get the value of that property.

Comment: Thanks, this with the help of a coworker sent me in the right direction.  Drag and Drop is made so simple in WPF but the doDragDrop() doesn't seem as useful or effective as a custom built one.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to put the MouseEnter event in the border of my data template.  This template is bound to my objects.  Instead of trying to determine if the mouse was hovering over the object before performing an action, the

```
object_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{
     if(....)
     else
}
```

event fired each time an object was "entered into by the mouse" and I used conditional statements to decide how to handle the event.

Thanks for the previous suggestions regarding mouse events.